# Can you round a variable divided/multiplied by another number to the nearest hundreths?

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding, converters

I am making a weight converter. After a few people using it, some realized that it showed way too many decimals at the end. How can I make it so that it only shows up to the hundredths?

```
document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("lbsInput").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  document.getElementById("output").style.visibility = "visible";

  let lbs = e.target.value;

  document.getElementById("gramOutput").innerHTML = lbs * 454;
  document.getElementById("kgOutput").innerHTML = lbs / 2.205;
  document.getElementById("ozOutput").innerHTML = lbs * 16;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: Use `toFixed()` method, it converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```
var num = 123.456789;
var result = num.toFixed(3);
```

Output:

```
"123.456"
```

Method 2: You can use `Math.round()` like this:

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
```

Output:

```
123.46
```

Comment: `toFixed()` is not a solution to round something to nearest hundredth (2 decimal places)